# What execution ordering guarantees are given by RCTDeviceEventEmitter emit

Tags: multithreading, react-native

In a react native app I am using events to alert my app to certain state changes in the background. These events come from different background threads, and are emitted to the javascript code using

```
getReactApplicationContext()
            .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
            .emit(channel, message);
```

What ordering guarantees can I expect to hold for the javascript code triggered by these emits? Specifically, for the following scenarios, in which cases is it guaranteed that the javascript code for event 1 gets executed before the javascript code for event 2?

1. Thread 1 first emits event 1, and then event 2
2. Thread 1 first emits event 1, then synchronises explicitly with thread 2, then thread 2 emits event 2.
3. Thread 1 first emits event 1, then thread 2 emits event 2 afterwards, and it is (through java's memory model) observable that thread 2 could only have emitted event 2 after thread 1.